# A subquery has set of 10 records with 5 columns , outer query has to create a column based on value inside the subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

For eg : Subquery

A subquery has returned rows with :

(Select roll_no , name , subject, mark , result from tablea )

```
Roll_no     Name   Subject         Mark   Result
 1           J       Math           90     P
 1           J       English        80     P
 1           J       Lang           30     F
 1           J       Science        60     P
 1           J       History        70     P
```

I want main query to create a indicator with all value from subquery and  if one record in the subquery has value F in the result column for the above 5 records  , then create 5 records in main-query with grade F for all records else P in all 5 records in main query

select a.* , grade from (Select roll_no , name , subject, mark , result from tablea ) as a

```
Roll_no     Name   Subject         Mark   Result    Grade
 1           J       Math           90     P          F
 1           J       English        80     P          F 
 1           J       Lang           30     F          F
 1           J       Science        60     P          F
 1           J       History        70     P          F
```

Comment: Please replace images with formatted text. Include sample data as well as desired output.

Comment: you mention queries but I see no queries

Comment: Like `CASE WHEN MIN(mark) OVER () = 'F' THEN 'F' ELSE 'P' END` ? I think it would help fi you shared your sql, and equally important, paste your data as text and format with stackoverflow markdown.

Comment: I updated according to your request @JNevill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a window function, you could do the following:

```
Select roll_no , name , subject, mark , result, 
  MIN(result) OVER () as Grade
from tablea
```

That's going to return the min(result) of the result set and repeat for each record, so even if one `F` appears, then every record will show `F`.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mxt7APPe)

Comment: Awesome , if i want to consider only for certain key , for eg i want to consider the record only for the key Roll_no 1 . How can i do it ? @JNevill

Comment: That is precisely what window function are made for. In fact, the use of a window function here was just a nice little side-effect where the window is "all records". For your case, you can add the following: `MIN(result) OVER (PARTITION BY roll_no) as Grade` and then it willy only consider that `min()` for each distinct `roll_no` window of records.